# Find line equation using another line's equation and the angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So, I have the problem described exactly as in the figure below. I want to find the equation for the green line given the data described in the figure.

I know that $$\tan(\text{angle of elevation for the black line}) = -\frac{a}{b}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If the slopes of two lines are $m_1$ and $m_2$, the angle $\theta$ between them  is such that:
$$
\tan \theta= \left|\dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2} \right|
$$

> You have $m_1=-a/b$ and, for $\tan \theta >0$ find $m_2= \dfrac{m_1-\tan \theta}{1+m_1 \tan \theta}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** The vector $(a, b)$ is normal to the black line $ax + by + c = 0$, and hence we can produce a nonzero vector $\bf n$ normal to the green line by rotating $(a, b)$ by an angle of $\theta$; we can compute its components using a rotation matrix:
$${\bf n} := \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta \\ a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}.$$

> Now, as we'll see, we don't need to use the point ${\bf p}_2$, so we may as well denote ${\bf p} := {\bf p}_1$. 
>  By construction a point ${\bf x} = (x, y)$ is on the green line iff the vector from the intersection point ${\bf p} = (x_0, y_0)$ to $\bf x$ is orthogonal to $\bf n$, so the equation of the green line is: $${\bf n} \cdot ({\bf x} - {\bf p}) = 0 .$$ One can expand this in terms of components and, e.g., rearrange to write the equation of the line in standard form.